# Pixel value to image using Java

Tags: pixel

Here my pattern, the following four items are pixels from a photo (32x32 px size):

(1,2, #958B85), (21,27, #777769), (12,11, #6A655D), (15,4, #AAB3B2)
Legend: (x, y, colour)

How can I convert those pixel values into image ?

Comment: What would you expect this image to look like?

Comment: It’s gonna be a little bit difficult because it’s a 32x32 px but it’s gonna be a colourful image with greeneries